# Receiving an EWS error in C# about Ids in EWSLegacyId format which is not supported by current version

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

All of sudden I've been receiving errors that says

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: The EWS Id is in EwsLegacyId format which is not supported by the Exchange version specified by your request. Please use the ConvertId method to convert from EwsLegacyId to EwsId format.

Has anyone received the above error message?

I noticed the latest version I can select for ExchangeService is ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1, however my exchange server is currently on version 15. Not sure if it is due to that.

There's a bunch of Ids I would need to do ConvertId for (items/folders) and wanted to know if there is a simpler and more concise fix.

Comment: Are the Id's currently in the EWSLegacyId format ? Any requestserverversion over Exchange2007_SP1 should be using the same Id format so it would have to be some pretty legacy code to be a problem. The Major build number of Exchange eg 15 hasn't changed since 2013 so it could mean you 2013,2016 or 2019 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/new-features/build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=exchserver-2019, the Managed API is now open source so you can compile the latest from github https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api

Comment: Same issue here: No comments so far but maybe (if this persists) someone comes up with a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77651523/retrieving-emails-using-ews-notificationevent-microsoft-exchange-webservices-da/77652287#77652287

Comment: This error literally came out of the blue recently and nothing has really changed regarding my exchange server. My Ids technically should not be in legacy format because I definitely have 2013+. I read legacy Ids are more in older versions like 2007 or office 365. I'm glad I'm not the only one receiving this error, but it is very frustrating.

Comment: Its it OnPrem on Exchange Online ?, if its OnPrem it would have to then be related to the most recent CU that was applied to the server as that would be the only code change. If its Online then they most likely broke it in the latest update. Either way you should log it as a bug with Microsoft, for what it's worth i tried the repro from the other link in Exchange Online and couldn't repro the issue but that could be just down to the patch level of my tenant.