# Retrieving emails using EWS NotificationEvent (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemEvent) fails

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I was running a source that retrieves emails from NotificationEvent's itemID, as shown in the source below.

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemEvent itemEV = 
(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemEvent)e;
Item item = Item.Bind(ewsClient, itemEV.ItemId);
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage emailData = 
(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage)item;
```

Recently, an error occurred at `Item.Bind`, and the following message appeared.

> The EWS Id is in EwsLegacyId format which is not supported by the
> Exchange version specified by your request. Please use the ConvertId
> method to convert from EwsLegacyId to EwsId format.

It looks like the itemID of NotificationEvent needs to be converted, but I would like to know if there is a workaround.
(It appears that the ID format of EWS needs to be changed, but I thought it would be a bit strange to change the value of capital k from EWS, so I asked this question.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems they broke something in EWS - I hope this is only temporary, but if you need a workaround too, this works for now:

```
public string ConvertLegacyEwsIdToEwsId(string smtpAddress, string entryId)
{
    AlternateId inputId = new AlternateId
    {
        Format = IdFormat.EwsLegacyId,
        Mailbox = smtpAddress,
        UniqueId = entryId
    };

    AlternateId alternateId = (AlternateId)ewsClient.ConvertId(inputId, IdFormat.EwsId);
    return alternateId.UniqueId;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample code.
Finally, I was able to retrieve the email object that was successfully notified using the source below.

Comment: ---
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemEvent itemEV = (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemEvent)e;

AlternateId inputId = new AlternateId
{
    Format = IdFormat.EwsLegacyId,
    Mailbox = "mailaddress",
    UniqueId = itemEV.ItemId.UniqueId
};
AlternateId alternateId = (AlternateId)ewsClient.ConvertId(inputId, IdFormat.EwsId);
ItemId convertitemId = new ItemId(alternateId.UniqueId);

Item item = Item.Bind(ewsClient, convertitemId);
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage emailData = (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage)item;
---